# XML Schema minOccurs

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following schema: (excerpt)

```
<xs:element name= "off" minOccurs="1">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name= "id" type = "xs:integer"/>
      <xs:element name= "part" minOccurs="1">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name= "id" type = "xs:integer"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name= "asdf" type = "xs:float"/>
     </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Now, by intuition I would have guessed, that the following tree would be allowed by that:

```
<oof>
 <id>123</id>
 <part>
  <id>134</id>
 </part>
 <part>
  <id>454</id>
 </part>
 <asdf>234123.0</asdf>
</oof>
```

However, xmllint states, that the second  was not excpected, but  was excpected. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you haven't specified maxOccurs, it is assumed to be 1 hence the second occurance of part is causing the message displayed by xmllint

Comment: got it.. it hought that maxOccurs defaults to infinity.